# how to avoid dead lock in Thread

Tags: deadlock, java-threads

Java threads almost have deadlock problem, how to take effective and simple solutions to avoid this problem

`Java.lang.Thread.State:BLOCKED`

Comment: Use `synchronized` block  or semaphore!

Comment: The thread state `BLOCKED` does not imply that there is a deadlock. Further, the sentence “Java threads almost have deadlock problem” makes no sense at all.

Answer (score 0):

Say you have the fork in your hand and I have the knife. We both want to eat the steak in the plate in front of us. I want the fork, you want the knife. None of us can eat. Deadlock. It's not about Java but how you take the locks in order to avoid this type of situation.

One way to solve the above problem is to agree that no one shall grab the knife prior to grabbing the fork. Both knife and fork should be released once used.